# When I select multiple row names using multchoice (easygui) it is unclear how to send the entire rows to the same csv (append). Singles work well

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, easygui

```
import pandas as pd
from easygui import *

df = pd.read_csv('allfoods.csv')

choices = ["Egg", "Milk" ]

choice = multchoicebox(msg, title, choices)

if choice == "Egg" :

  df2 =  df[df.Food=="Egg"].head()
  print (df2)

  df2.to_csv('outfile.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False, header=False)


if choice == "Milk" :

  df3 =  df[df.Food=="Milk"].head()
  print (df3)

  df3.to_csv('outfile.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False, header=False)

else: pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the change below fixed it.

choice = multchoicebox(msg, title, choices)
print ("Reply was: %s" % str(choice))

for i in range(len(choice)):

print (choice[i])
  df1 =  df[df.Food==choice[i]].head()
  print (df1)

df1.to_csv('outfile.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False, mode='a', header=False)